# webpage in public_html don't show up in google search

Tags: html, pagerank

Is there a way to get my webpage which is stored in my public_html folder on my server to show up in google? Right now I don't get any hit when searching the title.

Comment: Google can take a while to index pages. And it takes even longer if it doesn't have links to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo

Basically what you need to do is turn your page into a SEO beast. SEO stands for Search Engine Optimization. You need to follow googles guidelines:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291?hl=en

You need to add certain tags and best practices to your website to get googles bots to scan your site better and get a better understanding of how your website is setup. @Guarav Genius also gave you a link to google webmasters which should provide some more information on how to get your website to show up on google.

Answer (score 2):

Sign Up for Google Webmaster and list your site there, here is the link...
https://www.google.com/webmasters/